# Angularjs animation restrict for class

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

Good day. I have a question:
is there any way to restrict to angular adding additional classes for element for animation?

i.e.: when element has some transition in CSS, and i try to add another class with ng-class, it also adds: class-add, class-add-active.

I don't want angular to add this classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there's a way to do it, you need to add a filter on class names you want to animate via a regex

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']).config(['$animateProvider', function($animateProvider){     
  $animateProvider.classNameFilter(/myClass/);
}]);

<div class="myClass"> ... </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've spent dozens of hours searching :D